# Winform Datagridview doesn't display data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Binding data is not working for my datagridview.

Here is .cs file

```
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Magacin
{
    public partial class AnalizaPartneraGlobal : Form
    {
        List<Int_String> partneri = Komercijalno.Partner.Lista();
        List<NeaktivniPartner> neaktivniPartneri = new List<NeaktivniPartner>();
        public AnalizaPartneraGlobal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(Int_String partner in partneri)
            {
                double danaBezProdaje = (DateTime.Today - Komercijalno.Partner.PoslednjaKupovina(partner._int)).TotalDays;
                if ( danaBezProdaje > 31)
                {
                    NeaktivniPartner np = new NeaktivniPartner();
                    np.ppid = partner._int;
                    np.naziv = partner._string;
                    np.danaBezKupovine = danaBezProdaje;
                    neaktivniPartneri.Add(np);
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = M.List.ConvertToDataTable(neaktivniPartneri);
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public class NeaktivniPartner
    {
        public int ppid;
        public string naziv;
        public double danaBezKupovine;
    }
}
```

As you can see i only have `button` and `dataGridView`

If i recall earlier i have been doing `dataGridView.dataSource = myGenericList;` worked perfect but for some reason now it is not working so i tried converting it to `DataTable` but still not working. Then i added `AutogenerateColumns` and still not displaying any data or columns. And after that tried adding `Refresh()` but still nothing.

In debugger it shows that datagridview has rows inside it:
[image]

Beside this i tried:

- Deleting datagridview and do everything again
- Close VS and open it again
- Tried doing it with `BindingList`
- Tried binding list to datasource directly

Code behind `ConvertToDataTable`

```
public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
{
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
           TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Comment: Can you also add the code behind this call: ConvertToDataTable

Comment: @Isma Look at edit

Comment: have you tried setting `dataGridView1.DataSource = null`before you assign the datatable ?

Comment: Tried it and still nothing. I have added debugging at the start of button click to see `row.count()` inside `list` and `datagridview.rows`. First click both return 0 (which is expected) but second click list return 20k and dgv returns 0.

Comment: I am confident the problem is with the class `NeaktivniPartner`… it is missing a `get`ter and `set`ter. The `DataGridView.DataSource` won’t know what to display without them.

Comment: @JohnG Yeap. I forgot that. It was bothering me about year ago but i forgot it. Just added `{get; set;}` and it works now. Post it as answer or i will in 2 days if you do not. Thanks :)

Comment: You can answer the question if you like. It is satisfaction enough for me to know that we were able to determine why it did not work in the first place. Good Luck ;-)

Comment: @JohnG Hahaha okay :)

Comment: Try this: properties names in class and columns name in datagridview would be same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JohnG referred to problem in comments but i will post full answer here.

So solution was to instead of this:

```
public class NeaktivniPartner
{
    public int ppid;
    public string naziv;
    public double danaBezKupovine;
}
```

i set this:

```
public class NeaktivniPartner
{
    public int ppid { get; set; }
    public string naziv { get; set; }
    public double danaBezKupovine { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a BindingSource as the DataSource for your DataGridView. Also, the Refresh method of a Control is for rendering the control and has no effect on its DataSource.

Here's a simple example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<TestModel> _dataList = new List<TestModel>();
    private BindingSource _binding = new BindingSource();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        _binding.DataSource = _dataList;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _binding;
    }

    private int _counter = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            _counter++;
            _dataList.Add(new TestModel()
            {
                ID = _counter,
                Name = "Name " + _counter
            });
        }
        _binding.ResetBindings(false);
    }

    private class TestModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about your issue. I just discovered why DataGridView will not display data-bound list. It turns out that the grid view does not generate columns automatically.
In order to generate grid columns, you would have to change NeaktivniPartner class to use member properties, not member variables as following:

```
public class NeaktivniPartner
{
    public int ppid {get; set;}
    public string naziv {get; set;}
    public double danaBezKupovine {get; set;}
}
```